# i18n custom validation error handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, internationalization

In a rails 3.2.16 app form submission, error messages are not flowing i18n-ized to the view. Based on the following model definition

```
  validate :not_overlap

  def not_overlap
    errors.add(:start, 'message') if overlaps?
  end
```

I have not been able to insert the translation code helper

The following is the locale file:

```
  activerecord:
    models: 
      optionrate: "Options"
    attributes:
      optionrate:
        start: "Start"
        end: "End"
    errors:
      models:
        optionrate:
          attributes:
            start:
              not_overlap: "Dates overlap existing options."
            end:
              not_overlap: "Dates overlap existing options"
```

I am also unsure about the

```
<% @optionrate.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %><%= msg %>
```

command and its i18n...

...which sort of makes 3 rabbits to run after

1. how to invoke a translation message
2. how to codify it properly in the locale file
3. how to also handle the generic msg for i18n
   I assume there is a hierarchy as to how these get processed.  Combined it is a geometrically-growing mess of alternatives.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the second argument to errors.add needs to be the symbol of the error message you're trying to add. So:

```
errors.add(:start, :not_overlap)
```

You've probably fixed this by now though!

Comment: Right; it's either the string or a symbol for something to fish out...  I hadn't fixed it yet!  Thanks.